# JSON .NET asmx and Flex3

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex, json, asmx

i wrote webservice in .net which return json string

```
WebService(Namespace = "AndrewRowland")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        test Test = new test();
        Test.a = "one";
        Test.b = "two";
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(Test);

    }
}
```

and now i want to cosume this method 'HelloWorld' in Flex3 but i don't know how to ask about this metod what i done is to put corelib to my libs and wrote httpService:

:

```
 private function onJSONLoad(event:ResultEvent):void


 {

     var rawData:String = String(event.result);
     var manager = JSON.decode(rawData);

   }
```

```
<mx:HTTPService id="service" resultFormat="text"
                url="http://localhost:50174/Service1.asmxn"
                result="onJSONLoad(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know .NET well.  But, If you're calling a SOAP Web Service, use the [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) tag instead of HTTPService.  With WebService you can can call a specific method on the WSDL, kind of like this:

```
service.HelloWorld();
```

You should read through the [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html) for more details.